# iPhone memory leak help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, autorelease

This code is leaking, the performance tool blames two leaks on this block of code. If i comment it out the leak doesn't happen. Any help pinning it down would be greatly appreciated.

Leaks:

Malloc 48 bytes

NSCFarray 32 bytes

Code Block:

```
    NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Add", @"Edit", nil];
    segmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:myArray];
    [myArray release];
    [segmentControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
    [segmentControl setMomentary:YES];
    [segmentControl addTarget:self action:@selector(addOrEditPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    UIBarButtonItem *myBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentControl];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myBarButtonItem;
    [myBarButtonItem release];
```

Comment: why don't you identify the lines that allocate memory and then check for corresponding frees?

Comment: ...or make your alloc auto-release....

Comment: iPhone SDK does not have garbage collection, so no auto-release for us!

Comment: There is still an auto-release pool ... You can call it manually. Also, take a look at the main entry point to all iphone application's, its setup with an autorelease pool...

Comment: @taspeotis: I realise there is no garbage collection. But there is a  NSAutoreleasePool

Comment: There isn't always an NSAutoreleasePool. Though it's true there often is. It depends what's called your code and whether you set one up yourself or not.

Comment: I traced through, and every alloc has a release somewhere in the code, I experimented with releasing some things again but that caused (as expected) the uncaught exception

Comment: Sorry guys, I made a rookie mistake on this one. I was looking inside a block within the method, and missed a line of code before the block, which was leaking. Gotta release the ivars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `segmentControl` is `nil` when you enter the code block and is being released somewhere else in your code (like `dealloc` or `viewDidUnload`) then you are doing nothing wrong.

Have you tried running your code under the static analyzer (Xcode menu: Build | Build & Analyze)?

Instruments can sometimes generate false positives when searching for leaks. If the leaked memory doesn't accumulate over time, your worst case scenario is that your program is leaking a total of 80 bytes. Leaks that grow over time are what you should be concerned about.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the growing over time type, every time I load this view it seems to leak the memory.

Comment: Static analyzer didn't point out the leak, good tool though. I still am accumulating memory somehow from this code. Is there any way for segmentControl, an instance variable, to have a value other than nil when viewDidLoad is called? assuming I haven't overridden initWithNibName:bundle:

Comment: If that code is in your viewDidLoad method, you should be releasing segmentControl and setting it to nil in viewDidUnload. However, viewDidUnload is only likely to be called due to a memory warning. When you say you are repeatedly "loading" this view: are you reusing the same view controller instance, or creating a new one each time?

Answer (score 1):

Is segmentControl meant to be released?

Comment: I wonder is that Malloc 48 leak actually a UISegmentedControl 48 leak that's just being misreported by Cocoa?  I agree with taspeotis that you should consider whether to release segmentControl at the end...

Answer (score 0):

myArray's retain count is still one after this section of code. When you add it to the initWithItems to create the segmentControl, it now has a reference to the object.

Is that possibly the leak?

Comment: He's releasing myArray after that though, so there shouldn't be a leak.

Answer (score 0):

No alloc is required when you create the array.

> NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Add", @"Edit",
>   nil];

Use :

```
+ (id)arrayWithObjects:(id)firstObj, ...
```

Try it this way, this also doesn't needs `release`.

Comment: I had that originally, changed it in an attempt to narrow the problem by avoiding autoreleased objects.

Comment: .... so what the variant scope of the 'segmentControl' ?

 try add [segmentControl release];

Comment: sorry , I have add you code block in a clean basic app, and use Instruments to trace the Leak issue , but no memory leak was occupy ... maybe my trace way is not correct ? I guess that seem other code cause the problem ....

Answer (score 0):

Is segmentControl a property? Do you nil it in viewDidUnload?

Comment: In dealloc i have segmentControl released, what is the effect of setting it to nil in viewDidUnload?

Comment: You didn't answer my question: is it a property? If so, and it's defined with "retain" then setting it does a retain, and your release only gets rid of the alloc.